# How to operate a relay (24 VDC 8 mA) from a 4-20mA signal?

Tags: relay, solenoid, plc, 4-20ma

I have a PLC that can output a 24 VDC, 4-20 mA signal, but it cannot be turned off - the lowest it can go is 4 mA. I found a [relay](https://www.citrelay.com/Catalog%20Pages/RelayCatalog/J104D.pdf) (J104D2C24VDC.20S, 24VDC, 0.20W) that per the datasheet operates at 24 VDC, ~8 mA, but I found that the contacts are closed even at 4 mA.

Is there a simple way to convert a 4-20 mA signal to 0-24 VDC to operate this (or similar) relay?

Comment: Certainly. Three resistors and a comparator would happily do it. An output buffer transistor and you can drive any coil current you want.

Comment: Relays make poor comparators due to the hysteresis and tolerances on hysteresis.  So it takes far less current to hold on to the keeper before it must release it than the max current where it must activate it.  The rated current is optimized for speed and heat rise as tradeoffs.

I made this table based on the majority of all power relays which are defined as contact rating > 2Amps.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/raRZS.png

Comment: "*I found a relay ...*". We'll [edit] the question to include the datasheet link for the relay! (Datasheet link - not Amazon or Ali-what's-it ad. "No datasheet? - No sale!")

Comment: Can you get a PLC with a discrete output?  Using an analog current loop output is a bit of a waste.  If you can't get a discrete output, there are dedicated products that will close a relay when a 4-20 mA signal reaches a setpoint.  Quick google result: [here](https://www.sitron.com/en/produto/tr202-rele/) and hilariously mistranslated one: [here](https://www.disibeint.com/products-en/Control-relays/Current-relays/Loop-4-20-mA-113.html).

Comment: @Theodore My PLC (custom built by the company I work for) has 4 discrete outputs and 4 analog current outputs, and the system I'm controlling has 6 solenoids. I could use a second PLC, but I'm trying to see if I can get away with just one by putting some solenoids on the analog current loops.I just put some resistors on my relay coil circuit and got the contacts to stay open at around 2.75mA so I might just throw a resistor into the current loop to bring it down.

Comment: @kevindarm The problem with that approach is that it depends on the characteristics of the relay.  Can you expect it to stay the same?  Have you tried putting a resistor in *parallel* with the relay coil?

Comment: @Theodore May I ask the reasoning why putting the resistor in parallel might be better? I don't doubt you, just struggling to identify the reasoning myself.

Comment: If the relay is 24V 8mA or 3000 ohms, you can put a 1500 ohm resistor in parallel (1000 ohm total) so the relay will see about 1.6 mA to 7 mA and 4-20V. Or use a 12 mA current sink.

Comment: The relays linked (you didn't specify which one and there are many) pick up at 75% of rated voltage but don't drop out until 10%. That's a ratio of  7.5:1. That means that if 20 mA could pick the relay then current would have to fall to 20 / 7.5 = 2.7 mA to release. Meanwhile the 4 - 20 mA current source has a ratio of only 20:4 = 5:1. The problem can't be solved by series or parallel resistor only.

Comment: Ahhh I see the problem. Resistor in series is creating a voltage divider, and my PLC isn't going to increase the voltage on the analog output current loop to compensate. If I put the resistor in parallel, the resistance is capped at the relay coil's resistance, so I'm not going to be able to limit the current. Looks like I need to find a completely different approach.

Comment: I made a simulation that uses a 1.8k resistor on the 4-20 mA signal, and from there I use a 6.2 volt zener to the 3k coil of the relay. The relay sees 800 mV to 18V for the 4-20 mA current signal. If this question is re-opened, I'll post the simulation. But it's simple enough.

Comment: @PStechPaul The standard load resistor for 4-20 mA current loop is 250 ohms. 20 mA at 1.8 k requires 36 volts, which may not be available in a 4-20 mA current loop system. IMHO, a precision (if necessary) resistor, a voltage reference (if necessary) and a comparator plus an external drive transistor offer a good approach.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help. @Transistor put it concisely. I need a ratio of 7.5:1 between max and min voltage to operate the relay, and I only have a ratio of 5:1 between my max and min current outputs from the PLC. Unsolvable with passive components. I can either go more complex, or I can cave in and borrow another PLC.

Comment: I provided a solution with one resistor and one zener diode. It will work well with the PLC if it has a compliance of 24 VDC. The 1.8k resistor drops 7.2 volts at 4 mA. Then the 6.2V zener starts conducting and with the 3k resistance of the relay coil, the total voltage drop at 20 mA is 24V, with 18V on the relay. If that is not enough, perhaps a 12V relay should be chosen, if a simple circuit is required.

Answer (score 3):

It would be better to use a comparator with a separate power supply, which would allow the use of a more robust relay than the sensitive one you've found, however here is a way to that does not require a power supply.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2q3tG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Q1 and Q2 divert about 4mA from the input. D1 (a white or blue LED) subtracts enough voltage from the coil that they can do their work. The compliance of the 4-20mA source has to provide pretty close to 24V in order to operate the relay reliably.

[image]

Comment: That is a very good answer, but by subtracting 4 mA from the signal, at 20 mA it will drive 12 mA into the 3k relay coil, for 32 volts. The 10k resistor shunts an extra 4 mA. This is fine if the source compliance is limited to 24V, or if it can be adjusted to about 15 mA maximum. Otherwise, a 75 ohm resistor for R1 provides almost zero voltage up to 8 mA, and then the full 24V at 20 mA, with 27V in.

Answer (score 0):

A J-FET can form a current bypass around the relay coil at low current.
This FET does not conduct if the voltage across R1 is above the gate thresold voltage. At low current the FET begins to conduct and *thieves* current from the coil. The 9V version of the rely matches here.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxiowK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Blue is the relay current and yellow the FET current
[image: Current takeover fet/relay]

Answer (score 0):

Now that this question is accepting answers, I submit my idea, which is about as simple as possible with one resistor and one zener diode:

[image: Relay Drive 4-20 mA]